# PHP 5 Regex - finding match in online editor but not in local code

Tags: php, regex

Here's my issue:

```
$keyword = "md";
$pattern = "/\W" . $keyword . "{1}|" . $keyword . "{1}\W/i";
$str = "asdfmd";
$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $str);
```

For some reason, this pattern works on http://regex101.com/#pcre and http://www.regextester.com/ but when I use it on my code, it doesn't find a match. Any idea why this is happening? Thank you in advance for your responses!

Other $str that work online: "mdasdf", " mdasdf", "asdfmd ".

Update:
Hopefully this helps. Here is my input into regex101

```
Test: /\Wmd|md\W/gi

Strings:
 mdasas*
mdasas*
asmdas
asasmd*
asasmd *
 asasmd*
```

Note: The second to last string has a trailing whitespace, * indicates found in regex101

Comment: yeah, `$result = preg_match_all()` will just return a boolean result. `preg_match_all($pattern, $str,$result);` makes more sense, unless you **wanted** a boolean result.

Comment: Writing `{1}` in a pattern is always useless, you can remove it.

Comment: @philtune preg_match_all will return an integer or **false on failure**, hence the notice in the documentation to use strict comparison when using the return value of preg_match_all. edit: also see the comment below

Comment: There is no character from the `\W` character class in your string, so it's normal you can't find a match.

Comment: @Rangad, good catch. Was just going from memory. Those are always tricky.

Comment: bigjolly, are you sure that the pattern that matches is the same as the one you posted? `\W` should match any *non-word* characters. And you have none of them in your example. edit: (Just writing out what Casmimir said ;))

Comment: @Rangad He use space in his examples for non-word character. See " mdasdf" and "asdfmd ".

Comment: Hey everyone! Thanks for your responses. The idea is that the regex would match `$keyword` (in this case "md") if it is in the beginning or end of the `$str`, but not in the middle. I've tried `\n` and `\v` and neither tokens are working. Also, because the string could have multiple words, the leading or trailing space is optional. As for `$result`, the return of a 1 for true or False for error is fine; I'm not interested in what the match is at this point, just that there was a match. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Please read http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Maybe you must write `preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $result);`

I write `maybe` because I don't know what you really want to receive. Check, that before `PHP 5.4.0` parameter `matches` was not optional.

**UPD**

For `start` and `end` of string try using simple `"/^".$keyword."|".$keyword."$/i"`

Comment: Thanks @CnapoB! We're using PHP 5.5. That was one of the first things I checked thinking it may be an issue. However, for SnG, I added `$result` to the `preg_match_all` and still returning no matches found.

Comment: @bigjollygiant14 please see the UPD

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out what was going on. The text input area on those websites is treated as one long string, which is why the matches were showing when they shouldn't have been. I was matching with the wrong tokens. Thanks again for your help!

-W